# Exercise 5C10 in Isaacs' Finite Group Theory

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

**Problem:** Suppose that $G$ is simple group and has an abelian Sylow $2-$subgroup of order $8$. Show that the order of $G$ is divisible by $7$.

Is there any hint to solve this problem? I'll be glad if one gives an answer.

Here's my start:

Let $|G| = 8k$ with $2\nmid k$. Then $n_2 = 1 \mod 2$, and $n\mid k$. Since $G$ is simple, $n_2 \neq 1$. After that I get stuck.

Comment: what do you think of the question.... ? you tried something?

Comment: Remember that a consequence of Sylow's third is that if there is only one Sylow p-subgroup then it is normal. That will factor into the proof if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Look at the 3 statements in Sylow's theorem.

Comment: I only do the following: Let $\left| G \right| = 8k$ and $2$ doesn't divide $k$. Then, ${n_2} \equiv 1(2)$ and 
$\left. {{n_2}} \right|k$. Since $G$ is simple, 
${n_2} \ne 1$. How can I show that 
$\left. 7 \right|k$?

Comment: @egrtomath : I assure you that just sylow theorems are not enough... this question has been already asked here but it has got closed for some reason..

Comment: Use this fact that $\frac{N_G(H)}{C_G(H)}$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $Aut(H)$.

Comment: @Praphulla Koushik: You are right. But I have just noticed that there exists a note in Isaac's book that if a Sylow $2−$subgroup of a simple group is abelian, then it must be elementary abelian. So, the nonzero elements in this Sylow $2−$subgroup have order two. This means that $G$ has at least $7$ elements of order $2$. Is it useful tool to prove?

Comment: I was about to mention that... In our case that sylow $2$ subgroup has to be $\mathbb{Z}_2\times \mathbb{Z}_2\times \mathbb{Z}_2$... Now I guess Babgen's hint would be useful... what would be automorphism group of $\mathbb{Z}_2\times \mathbb{Z}_2\times \mathbb{Z}_2$ atleast the cardinality?

Comment: Good points: $(1)$ According to Burnside celebrated result, $|G|\neq p^{a}q^{b}$. $(2)$ According to Brodkey theorem, if $S\in Syl_p(G)$ is abelian in finite group $G$, then there exists $T\in Syl_p(G)$ such that $S\cap T=core_G(S)$. So we can see that under the conditions we have $n_2(G)\ge 2$ and certainly $|G|\neq p^aq^b$.

Comment: @B.S. : How would $|G|\neq p^aq^b$ is helpful :O

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik: I am trying to insert another prime numbers except $2$ in $|G|$.

Comment: @B.S. :Oh yes... :) That is a valid point and useful too :)

Comment: Duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/634211/problem-in-transfer-from-isaacs-finite-group-theory?rq=1

Comment: @B.S How can we see?

Comment: Also duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/628803/problem-5c-10-isaacs-finite-group-theory

Comment: @JackSchmidt: that question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/634211/problem-in-transfer-from-isaacs-finite-group-theory?rq=1 is not solved (Not even partially) and the other question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/628803/problem-5c-10-isaacs-finite-group-theory says page does not exist... so i do not think that citing them would be of any use...

Comment: @egrtomath : You heard about automorphism group of elementary abelian groups?

Comment: Since this is the third time this question has been asked recently, perhaps somebody should provide at least a summary of the solution or a complete sequence of hints. I don't have a copy of Isaacs' book to hand, so I don't know what results on transfer are available.

Comment: @DerekHolt : I am trying to work it out...all i could do is that too confirm sylow $2$ subgroup is $H=\mathbb{Z}_2\times \mathbb{Z}_2\times \mathbb{Z}_2$ and I believe that using $N_G(H)/C_G(H)\cong A\leq Aut(H)$ would be of some hope... I could see that $|Aut(H)|=7.6.4$ so I see a factor $7$ in  $|Aut(H)|$ so i do have some hope... I am just thinking about possibilities of centralizer and normalizer in this case... I have asked a question regarding that hoping for some help http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/636047/centralizer-normalizer-of-abelian-subgroup-of-a-finite-simple-group

Comment: @egrtomath: I have now more or less answered the question in http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/636047

Answer (score 8):

Isaacs's Prop 5.18 states that whenever $G$ is a finite group with an abelian Sylow $p$-subgroup $P$, then $Z(N_G(P)) \cap G' \cap P = 1$. In our case $G=G'$ so we get that $Z(N_G(P)) \cap P = 1$. Of course $Z(N_G(P)) \cap P = C_P( N_G(P))$ are exactly those elements of $P$ that are left alone by every conjugation from $N_G(P)$.

Since the group of conjugations from $N_G(P)$ is exactly $N_G(P)/C_G(P) \leq \newcommand{\Aut}{\operatorname{Aut}}\Aut(P)$, and since $P \leq C_G(P)$ so that $N_G(P)/C_G(P)$ must be a group of odd order, we are interested in the odd order subgroups of $\Aut(P)$ for $P$ an abelian group of order 8.

If $P=C_8$ then $\Aut(P) \cong C_2 \times C_2$ has no non-identity subgroups of odd order, so $N_G(P)/C_G(P) = 1$ and $N_G(P) = C_G(P)$ and $C_P( N_G(P)) = P \neq 1$. Oops.

If $P=C_4 \times C_2$ then $\Aut(P) \cong D_8$ has no non-identity subgroups of odd order, so oops again.

If $P=C_2 \times C_2 \times C_2$ then $\Aut(P) \cong \operatorname{GL}(3,2)$ has odd order subgroups of orders 1, 3, 7, and 21. The ones of orders 1 and 3 centralize some non-identity elements of $P$, so oops. The ones of orders 7 and 21 are fine.

The one of order 7 creates what is called AGL(1,8) fusion and produces the simple group PSL(2,8). The one of order 21 creates what is called AΓL(1,8) fusion and produces the simple group J1 and ${}^2G_2(3^{2n+1})$ for $n \geq 1$.

Comment: In the case $P=C_2\times C_2\times C_2$, why elements of orders 1 and 3 centralize some non-identity elements of $P$ and order 7 not?

Comment: You may try listing a few elements of order 1. See if you can find a pattern.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution:** Let $P$ be an abelian Sylow $2−$subgroup of the simple group $G$. If a Sylow $2−$subgroup of a simple group is abelian, then it must be elementary abelian. So, $P \cong {Z_2} \times {Z_2} \times {Z_2}$. Recall that for the elementary abelian group $G$ of order ${p^n}$, 
$Aut\left( G \right) \cong GL\left( {n,p} \right)$. Note that 
$\left| {GL\left( {n,p} \right)} \right| = \prod\limits_{i = 0}^{n - 1} {\left( {{p^n} - {p^i}} \right)} $. So, 
$\left| {Aut\left( P \right)} \right| = 7.6.4 = 168$. Also note that 
$\frac{{{N_G}\left( P \right)}}{{{C_G}\left( P \right)}} \cong Aut\left( P \right)$
$ \Rightarrow $
$\left| {{N_G}\left( P \right)} \right| = \left| {{C_G}\left( P \right)} \right|.\left| {Aut\left( P \right)} \right| = \left| {{C_G}\left( P \right)} \right|.168$. Hence, 
$\left. 7 \right|\left| {{N_G}\left( P \right)} \right|$. By Langrange, we are done.

Comment: Thank you very much  Praphulla Koushik and  Babgen.

Comment: In general, you only know that $N_G(P)/C_G(P)$ is isomorphic to a *subgroup* of ${\rm Aut}(P)$, not necessarily to the whole of ${\rm Aut}(P)$. In fact what you wrote is clearly not right, because $|N_G(P)/C_G(P)|$ must be odd.

Comment: @DerekHolt : why should $|N_G(P)/C_G(P)|$ has to be odd :O could you please explain... suppose it is even then it has an element of order $2$ so Automorphism group should have an element of order $2$ ... Is that something which is not quite possible or for some other reason :O Please help me to see this..

Comment: It has to be odd because $C_G(P)$ contains $P$, which is a Sylow $2$-subgroup of $G$.

Comment: @Derek Holt: Thanks a lot.